# Comparing slopes in mixed-effect model

Tags: lme4-nlme, mixed-model

My data looks like the attached picture. The dependent variable indirectly measured physical activity. I tried to use mixed-effect model rather than RM Anova, because my actual data is imbalanced.

[image]

In this data, my research question is to figure out

1. How treatment effects are different
2. How genotype effects are different
3. How physical activity change over time.

What I really want to do is to compare each slope of the physical activity change within day1, day2, and day3 (like..animal a: (4.5-2.5)/4 vs (4.5-2.9)/4 vs (4.8-2.6)/4, not exactly in this way but.. that's what I want to compare).

I am currently using R so I wrote a code using lmer function. I formulated Day and Hour variables as continuous variable because I want to see the linear trends. I didn't assume the cross level interaction (between-within var interaction) in the model.

```
lmer(DV ~ 1 + treatment*genotype + Day + Hour + Day*Hour + (1 | ID), data)
```

I am assuming that testing Day*Hour interaction term may be one way to look at it, but I am not sure.. Could you give me any advice about it or give me another way to look at it?? Thank you so much for your time in advance.

Comment: Velcome to our site!

Answer (score 1):

One short thing: `Day + Hour + Day*Hour` can and should be replaced by `Day*Hour` (or `Day + Hour + Day:Hour`), because `*` allready includes the main effects [see the formula help page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html). 
Second, conditioning on `ID` doesn't make sense, because you only have one observation per `ID`. You should condition on `genotype` and `treatment`. As you wrote down a random intercepts model (without random slopes) I stick to this in my proposed model:

```
lmer(DV ~ 1 + Day*Hour + (1|treatment) + (1|genotype), data)
```

Comment: If there is variation in time or hour, this needs to be accounted for with a random slope. If not, and there is variation, the current model is mispecified. The type-one one error will increase with higher variation in the random slopes.